# VMWare 7: No audio mixer in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio

I am running Windows XP inside of VMWare, however I am unable to get the sound working inside of the virtual machine.  The host system is running windows 7 and it is a ASUS Republic of Gamers G73JH-A1 notebook.

When I go to volume control to test the sound it says "There are no active mixer devices available. To install mixer devices, Go to Control Panel and Other Hardware, and then click Add Hardware".

**EDIT:** I solved my problem by following the instructions here: http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2010/02/27/sound-in-windows-98-on-vmware/comment-page-1/#comment-20099
It says for windows 98 but it works great for xp, although on my xp installing directx was unnecessary.  Turns out the solution is hardware independant; you need to install drivers that vmware's virtual sound card can use, not drivers for your host system on your guest system.

Comment: Are the VMware tools installed properly? Does the virtual machine have a soundcard in its properties?

Comment: Well, when I look at the VM in workstation in the VM menu it says "reinstall VMware tools" so I take it that means it's already installed?  The virtual machine is using the default host sound card.

Comment: I found the solution, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by following the instructions here: http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2010/02/27/sound-in-windows-98-on-vmware/comment-page-1/#comment-20099 It says for windows 98 but it works great for xp, although on my xp installing directx was unnecessary. Turns out the solution is hardware independant; you need to install drivers that vmware's virtual sound card can use, not drivers for your host system on your guest system.